# Expansion of trignometric function around infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, mathematical-physics

I need to expand $\cos[\sqrt{x^2+a^2+b x}]$ around $x=\infty$ and want to keep terms only upto $x^{-3}$. Here $a$ and $b$ are constant. Should I first expand the function $\sqrt{(x^2+a^2+b x)}$ and then write the usual cosine series? Is this the right way to approach this question? If not then what should be the right approach. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that such an expansion exists?

Comment: What does $\theta$ has to do with $x$? You can just use $2\pi\cos\theta$ as a constant, say $c$.

Comment: @Andrei: True, you can do that. $\theta$ is a constant.

Comment: @gammatester: I don't really know if it exist. Can you show that it doesn't exist?

Comment: $\cos$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$